# C++ functions declaration with macros

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor

I am asking about a way to improve code readability

I was able to make a macro like this for a small library I'm making

```
#define fun(name, arg1, arg2) void name(int arg1, int arg2)
```

**NOTE**: int is an existent class, but I replace it with int so anyone can run it

This would allow me to use this code to create a function:

```
fun(testFunction, x, y) {
  // do stuff
  std::cout << x << y << std::endl;
}
```

and then in my main:

```
int main() {

  testFunction(1, 2);

  return 0;
}
```

This works great (at least in Visual Studio, haven't tested in GCC but I think it works there too).

Is it possible to make a macro that would be like:

```
#define fun name(arg1, arg2)     void name(int arg1, int arg2)
```

so a macro that would allow me to declare a function like:

```
fun testFunction(x, y) {
  // do stuff
}
```

The actual thing I am asking if is there a way to make a macro that
allows me to do this (for example)

```
CustomClassTemplate doStuff(CustomClass& arg1, CustomClassTemplate arg2, Library::Binary::Binary bin) {

  // do stuff

  return CustomClassTemplate(/*blah, blah, blah*/);

}
```

to this:

```
fun doStuff(arg1, arg2, bin) {
  // do stuff

  return CustomClassTemplate(/* blah blah blah*/);
}
```

you can create an empty class for each argument

Comment: _I am asking about a way to improve code readability_ You have not, in my opinion, achieved your goal.

Comment: The whole library takes the same argument types and the typenames are quite long, so it would be a bit hard to write a long name 4-5 times (I have more arguments), and then read it with always the same argument types

Comment: I don't think `int` is quite long.  Just 3 letters.

Comment: @Eljay As I said, int is a replacement so anyone can run this code. It's not the actual classes I am using (and I can't change the class names for compatibility with older code)

Comment: a function with too many arguments is a code smell that you are fighting at the wrong end. Instead of trying to hide complexity (in a place where you just add more complexity) you should try to decrease complexity by reducing number of arguments. Either group arguments that belong together in structs or try to find different ways. Having said that, I dont acually understand the question

Comment: Macros like this does not make the code more readable nor does it make it easier to troubleshoot compiler, linker, or runtime issues.

Comment: `fun testFunction(x, y) { // do stuff }` would expand to `name(arg1, arg2)     void name(int arg1, int arg2) testFunction(x,y) { // do stuff }` thats no function definition

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Let me edit the question to something. Also the arguments can't be converted to structs for backward compatibility

Comment: To progress this, I think you need to give us a real-world example from your real-life codebase.  You'll have to work it up into a [mre], but then we will be able to see the actual issue you're facing.

Comment: Having said which, a wrapper function with some of the arguments defaulted might be the way to go, it depends.

Comment: maybe add an example of what you'd like to write and what you expect it to be expanded to. Currently your last example of the `fun` macro and its useage dont make much sense

Comment: "Also the arguments can't be converted to structs for backward compatibility" sorry, but that doesnt make sense. Both the caller and implementation can use the arguments seperately even when they are packed in a struct on the interface, though, I am not going to question your motivation, the question stands on its own. Just warn you that there are better ways to solve your actual issue than the route you are currently taking

Comment: btw shouting (= WRITING ALL CAPS) that this isnt a duplicate will not prevent users from trying to find a duplicate, for me it rather had the opposite effect.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I am not writing it in all caps so they don't search. actually even better, if they find that this is a duplicate then they helped me to find something i couldn't do.. (I searched for 2 days and couldn't find what i am looking for)

Comment: *I am asking about a way to improve code readability*  Macros are not the "improve code readability" you are looking for.

Comment: @Eljay alright, but could you tell me if there is a way to do what I say in edit1? (I'm not limiting my question in macros, if it's possible with another way)

Comment: Maybe add a type alias if your types are getting too long?

Comment: `fun doStuff(arg1, arg2, bin)` I see.. not sure, a code from different language? are you trying to make C++look like something else?

Comment: You might be able to use `template` functions.  You could use `using` to make your parameter types less unwieldy.  You might be able to use *lambda* expressions with `auto` parameters (hard to say without a [mcve]).

Comment: Can you explain why you think  `fun(testFunction, x, y) {whatever(x,y);}` is more readable than `void testFunction(int x, int y) {whatever(x,y);}`??    If your justification amounts to "looks more like <a programming language that is not C++>" then forget it -  C++ code is supposed to make sense to people who take the trouble to understand C++, not to people who understand <a programming language that is not C++>.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie That is kind of an add-on I should add to the library, but yes the main reason is to make it easier to write new functions that will all do something different but need the exact same argument types

Comment: @Peter Making C++ look like a different programming language is not my main reason, but if it is possible I think it would make the library user-friendlier

Comment: @user18812922   What is your criteria for "user-friendlier"?  Having code that is to be compiled as C++, but is visually different from C++ (even worse, in this case, similar enough that a C++ developer will interpret it differently from what it actually is) is generally viewed as non-user-friendly.

Comment: @Peter Not to mention that preprocessor isn't so highly tested\regulated as C++ code according to standard. Both Vs and GCC got own features and quirks related to it. Any complex macro system requires additional testing for portability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already discovered: technically it can be done, but not in a `#define fun name(arg1, arg2)` and I think that's a good thing because you want to hide the fact that you're using macros while that should be clear enough. Also `fun doStuff(arg1, arg2, bin)` looks like a regular function declaration with empty parameter types (no parameter names) and returning `fun`.

What you already saw in the comments is that a lot of people don't agree that that using macros is a good thing and that will also be true for the people who will use your library or work on it, so you might take that into account when deciding to use it anyway.

Other points to take into account:

- copying and adapting code lines isn't that costly
- you can align the parameters to show that they're the same
- variations in function declarations will need more macros and longer names
- problems in functions with parameters are easier spotted when they are explicit

Comment: I just thought that "fun" could be like an identifier so the macro can then expand to ```blah blah blah name(blah arg1, blah arg2)```

Comment: You either have `#define var my expansion(I don't care)` where `var` is replaced with `my expansion(I don't care)` or `#define fun(par1, par2) do something with par1 and par2` where the parameters are replaced in the expansion. You may not even leave a space between `fun` and `(`.

Comment: @user18812922 Stop thinking "macro, macro, macro".  That is not the way.  Instead, take due account of Alan Birtles' comment above.  Do you know what he's driving at?  If not, I'd be happy to explain.